# Electron update-available and update-downloaded event not fire on client

Tags: electron, auto-update

when client call autoUpdater.checkForUpdates() i can see the server log display this:

> debug: Windows Update Search Query {
>         platform: ['windows_32'],
>         version: '2.0.0',
>         channel: 'stable'
>       }
>       debug: Applicable Channels['stable'] debug: Time Filter {
>         '>=': 2017 - 09 - 20 T08: 43: 10.000 Z
>       }
>       debug: Latest Windows Version {
>         assets: [{
>           name: 'DesktopAlert-3.0.0-ia32-full.nupkg',
>           platform: 'windows_32',
>           filetype: '.nupkg',
>           hash: '3536C0AD153B97027FEDE24CE1E9FE6C9863E04B',
>           size: 52623567,
>           download_count: 0,
>           fd: 'C:\Projects\electron-release-server\data\34506780-7e2c-487e-9bb6-67b47674e76b.nupkg',
>           createdAt: '2017-09-20T09:11:09.000Z',
>           updatedAt: '2017-09-20T09:11:09.000Z',
>           version: '3.0.0'
>         }],
>         channel: 'stable',
>         name: '3.0.0',
>         notes: '',
>         createdAt: '2017-09-20T08:43:31.000Z',
>         updatedAt: '2017-09-20T08:43:31.000Z'
>       }

but on the client, there is no event fired.
here is the client code for the auto update

```js
autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  console.log(event)
  mainWindow.webContents.send('update-not-available', {
    msg: event
  })
})

autoUpdater.on('update-available', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  console.log(event)
  mainWindow.webContents.send('update', {
    msg: event
  })
})
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  console.log(event)
  mainWindow.webContents.send('downloaded', {
    msg: event
  })
  const dialogOpts = {
    type: 'info',
    buttons: ['Restart', 'Later'],
    title: 'Application Update',
    message: process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
    detail: 'A new version has been downloaded. Restart the application to apply the updates.'
  }
  dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts, (response) => {
    if (response === 0) autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()
  })
})

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  console.log(event)
  mainWindow.webContents.send('checking', {
    msg: event
  })
})

autoUpdater.on('error', message => {
  console.error('There was a problem updating the application')
  console.error(message)
})
```

please help, did I forget anything?
P/s: sorry for the code format, don't know how to put code quote

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, plz post your comments if you got some solution for this.. :)

Comment: check your update URL: 
mac + windows 32bit: feedURL = `${updateServer}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}/stable`
windows 64bit: feedURL = `${updateServer}/update/windows_64/${app.getVersion()}/stable`

Comment: check the update server and port in config.js in the client and /config/local.js on update server
If you are using a channel that is not the stable channel, remember to add the channel to the update url

MacOS: update require both .zip and dmg file